# How to make DIV sticky so that its position does not change on scrolling the page in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, html

I am trying to implement a data table which should be scrollable but it should not change the position of TOP and Left blocks.

**This is my CSS:** I am applying this to TOP and LEFT Div blocks. But its not working.

```
.freeze {
    position:sticky;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

**MY HTML CODE**

```
<template>

 
  <lightning-card title="XLSX multi worksheet" icon-name="custom:custom14">

    <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
      <button onclick={download} class="btn success">Download</button>

      <!--xlsxMain component calling-->
      <c-xlsx-main header-list={xlsHeader} filename={filename} worksheet-name-list={workSheetNameList}
        sheet-data={xlsData}></c-xlsx-main>
    </div>

</lightning-card>


  <lightning-card>
    <lightning-tabset> <!-- variant="vertical" -->
      <lightning-tab label="Account Table">

        <lightning-layout>
          <lightning-layout-item size="12" padding="around-small" small-device-size="3" medium-device-size="6"
            large-device-size="3">

            <label>Show <select name="example_length" aria-controls="example" class="" onchange={optionChange}>
                <option value="10">10</option>
                <option value="25">25</option>
                <option value="50">50</option>
                <option value="100">100</option>
              </select> entries</label>

          </lightning-layout-item>
        </lightning-layout>
        <div class="slds-scrollable_y">
        <div>
          <lightning-datatable data={accountData} columns={accountColumns} key-field="id"
            onrowselection={getSelectedName} onheaderaction={handleHeaderAction}>
          </lightning-datatable>
        </div>
        </div>
      </lightning-tab>

      <lightning-tab label="Contact Table" title="2nd tab extended title">
        <div class="slds-scrollable_y">
        <div>
        <h1>Contact Table</h1>
        <div class="slds-scrollable">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <template for:each={contactHeader} for:item="header">
              <th key={header}>{header}</th>
            </template>
          </tr>
          <template for:each={contactData} for:item="item">
            <tr key={item.Id}>
              <th>{item.Name}</th>
              <th>{item.Phone}</th>
              <th>{item.Email}</th>
              <th>{item.Title}</th>
              <th>{item.Id}</th>
            </tr>
          </template>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
      </lightning-tab>

      <lightning-tab label="Item Three">
        Three Content !
      </lightning-tab>
    </lightning-tabset>

  </lightning-card>
</div>
</template>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please share c-xlsx-main code in short ? How did you implement the "Account table" & "Contact table" UI ? I assume you are using slds-grid for it.

Comment: Hi @Rohit, I have now updated my HTML code. Please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause of centre div not sticking is that the sticky position is applied to incorrect div.

First , you need to remove all `slds-scrollable`, `slds-scrollable_y` css classes from the markup.

Second , remove `freeze` css class as its not required on the outer div.

For fixing the centre div , you just need sticky position on the tab content.

Below is the sample code for the same (I've commented the data tables and added sample text for scroll):

```
<template>
<lightning-card title="XLSX multi worksheet" icon-name="custom:custom14">

  <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
    <button onclick={download} class="btn success">Download</button>

    <!--xlsxMain component calling-->
    <!-- <c-xlsx-main header-list={xlsHeader} filename={filename} worksheet-name-list={workSheetNameList}
      sheet-data={xlsData}></c-xlsx-main>-->
  </div>

</lightning-card>


<lightning-card>
  <lightning-tabset variant="vertical"> <!-- variant="vertical" -->
    <lightning-tab label="Account Table">

      <lightning-layout>
        <lightning-layout-item size="12" padding="around-small" small-device-size="3" medium-device-size="6"
          large-device-size="3">

          <label>Show <select name="example_length" aria-controls="example" class="" onchange={optionChange}>
              <option value="10">10</option>
              <option value="25">25</option>
              <option value="50">50</option>
              <option value="100">100</option>
            </select> entries</label>

        </lightning-layout-item>
      </lightning-layout>
      <div>
      <div>
        <!--<lightning-datatable data={accountData} columns={accountColumns} key-field="id"
          onrowselection={getSelectedName} onheaderaction={handleHeaderAction}>
        </lightning-datatable>-->
        Account table
      </div>
      </div>
    </lightning-tab>

    <lightning-tab label="Contact Table" title="2nd tab extended title">
      <div>
      <div class="sticky-div">
      <h1>Contact Table</h1>
      <div>
      <!--<table>
        <tr>
          <template for:each={contactHeader} for:item="header">
            <th key={header}>{header}</th>
          </template>
        </tr>
        <template for:each={contactData} for:item="item">
          <tr key={item.Id}>
            <th>{item.Name}</th>
            <th>{item.Phone}</th>
            <th>{item.Email}</th>
            <th>{item.Title}</th>
            <th>{item.Id}</th>
          </tr>
        </template>
      </table>-->
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

    </div>
    </div>
</div>
    </lightning-tab>

    <lightning-tab label="Item Three">
      Three Content !
    </lightning-tab>
  </lightning-tabset>

</lightning-card>
</template>
```

For the 2nd tab , we wrap the content in a div and apply `sticky-div` css class with below css :

```
.sticky-div {
  position: sticky;
  overflow: scroll;
  max-height: 50vh;/*Give max height as per your requirement */
}
```

We are not using any offset for sticky position since we want it to stick to the ancestor tab.

**Conclusion** : Apply sticky position & max-height for the div which you want to stick to its ancestor.

More about sticky position :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: Awesome!!! sticky-div is the trick. worked for me. Thank you a lot @Rohit. Please also help me with my other question regarding ExcelJS.

Comment: Welcome @PraveenBehera.  I will give it a try 